# Which release should I use for an ACER Aspire 1640 laptop?

Tags: acer, distro-recommendation

I have an Acer Aspire 1640 laptop with the following specs:

- Processor:  Intel Centrino 1.7 cache 2MB
- RAM: 1 GB
- Hard disk: 60 GB

Which Ubuntu release should I use? I am new to Linux.

Answer (score 2):

It seems your laptop will just [barely meet the minimum recommended system requirements](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements) for regular Ubuntu, particularly with regards to the amount of RAM present.

You can always try [making a LiveCD/LiveUSB of Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/download) to try on your machine and see how it performs before doing an actual installation. Keep in mind the performance will be slightly lower than once it is actually installed, however. If you decide that Ubuntu's performance is not good enough for you on that machine, you may also want to take a look at [Xubuntu](http://www.xubuntu.org/) and [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/), both of which are officially-recognized derivatives which aim to have better performance on low-end systems.

Answer (score -2):

No doubt! It's **Ubuntu 10.04 LTS version**. Every release after that is buggy until the next LTS release. I'm running it on an Intel Atom, which is weaker than yours. Remember to install `ccsm` (CompizConfig Settings Manager) after the installation for cool effects.